# Which is faster? Using PHP's cUrl library or invoking curl utility form shell_exec()

Tags: php, performance, curl

For a PHP project i have to access RESTful API. I was using curl to get familiar with the API. I can access the said API using both PHP's cUrl library and invoking the curl utility using PHP's shell_exec() function. Performance wise, which option would be better and why??

PS: I have my own server with root privilege.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My <strike>cautious *guess* would be</strike> not too useful test snippets shows that the [curl library](http://php.net/manual/book.curl.php) is more performant.

Edit: A [little test](https://gist.github.com/1050208) shows, that the library is faster, but not by much. Also, if you fetch millions of URLs, network latency will more likely be a bigger problem.

Comment: I'm with you. Saves the fork.

Answer (score 2):

Performance is pretty much exactly the same, because the same stuff is being executed internally. But you should use the API because it is cleaner.

Comment: Forking children costs more then using a lib in the same process.

Comment: @Otto Allmendinger : If it provide the same speed performance, shouldn't we just use `shell_exec` , it's only 1 line of code. It's cleaner. Please correct me - if I missed anything else.